# Spring Boot @Transactional Attribute with Multiple DataSource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hi I have two different methods and they use different datasources and transaction manager.I use `@Transactional` attribute and what I want, if my second method throws exception than my first method do its rollback. But it is not working, first method cant rollback. What am I missing?

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED,
    transactionManager = myTransactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void saveTest(TblTest testEntity)  {

    mySecondDBSource.saveTest2(testEntity);(use MyTransactionManager2) //Do job

    testTableRepository.save(testEntity); (Use myTransactionManager) //throws Exception

}

//in mySecondDBSource class there is another method
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED,
    transactionManager = "MyTransactionManager2", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void saveTest2(TblTest2 testEntity) {

    testTableRepository2.save(testEntity);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Data offers a way to handle so called **chained/distributed transactions** via [ChainedTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.6.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/transaction/ChainedTransactionManager.html).

See [spring-transactional-with-a-transaction-across-multiple-data-sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48954763/spring-transactional-with-a-transaction-across-multiple-data-sources).

Here is also a simple guide on [medium](https://medium.com/preplaced/distributed-transaction-management-for-multiple-databases-with-springboot-jpa-and-hibernate-cde4e1b298e4).

Comment: Yes it is working.Is it best way or different solutions?Regards

Comment: So far I didn't step over any other solution using the 'spring way'.

Comment: This post might also prove useful: https://metamorphant.de/blog/posts/2021-03-21-distributed-transactions-across-multiple-dbs-chainedtransactionmanager/