# Spring and hibernate. Transaction to both data sources

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, oracle, hibernate

In my application I need to perform several calculations on entity A, B, C. Due to entity C having a structure suited better for MongoDB I want to perform and commit transaction for entity A and B to oracle db and then entity C to mongo. However, if for any reason JVM crashed after commiting transaction to entity A, and B and commiting to mongo it will lead to incosistent database state. Is there any solution that I could use? I was thinking about using tempomary file that would be created before commiting to the oracle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring @Transactional with a transaction across multiple data sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48954763/spring-transactional-with-a-transaction-across-multiple-data-sources)

Comment: What if JVM crashed after T1?